# has_many & belongs_to is not working in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, belongs-to

I have created two models 1) Contact 2) Customer in my Rails application, now I want to join the two tables of these models. Tables are contacts & customers respectively. I am using following code:

1) contact.rb:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  unloadable
  has_many :customers
end
```

2) customer.rb

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact, :foreign_key => :contact_id`
end
```

3) customers_controller.rb

```
def new
  @customer = Customer.new
  @customer = Customer.find(:all,:include => :contact_id)
end
```

Here I am trying to access the primary key of contact table into customer table but it repeatedly gives this error "Association named 'contact_id' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?" Can any one help me on this?

Comment: What do you mean by "access the primary key of contact table into customer table"? Is there already a `contact_id` column in your `customers` database table?

Comment: Hi Gareth,Thanks for your reply, I do have a 'contact_id' column in my customers database table.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `include`, you should pass in the association name (in your case "`contact`") rather than the foreign key.

However, your description doesn't make clear that this is what you want to do, so if you can clarify your question I'll update this answer if it's wrong

Comment: I am using Redmine as my base application,There I am also using contacts & customers plugins of redmine,I want to access contact data on customer form(_form.html.erb).so that If I build a new customer form I need the information from contacts table(contact plugin)if that contact already exists.Is it possible?Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If I clearly understand you don't need to pluralize customer in the contact model :

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  unloadable
  has_many :customers
end
```

And you don't need to specified the name of the column who contain the foreign key

(sorry for my english)